# InDesign JS, select paragraph but no breaks and hyperlink destination

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I'm completely out of my depth here, I'm trying to create a script to select an entire paragraph, leaving out any break symbol (column/line/page) at the end of the paragraph AND any hyperlink destination at the beginning/end or middle of the paragraph.
**My main problem is that I do not know how to reference the different break symbols and the hyperlink destination symbol in JS.**

Looking around, I've found this script that did part of the job; with some tweaking, I removed the if altogether and just select the entire paragraph -2 at the end (not the most elegant solution, I know)

```
var ip = app.selection[0].paragraphs[0].insertionPoints;
if ( app.selection[0].paragraphs[0].characters[-1].contents == "\r" ) ip.itemByRange(0,-2).select();
else ip.itemByRange(0,-1).select();
```

Now I have the problem that my document is full of hyperlinks destinations and it would be great to be able to not have to recreate them all.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably `\uFEFF`.

This script: `alert(app.selection[0].contents.toSource());`

shows me this when I select the anchor symbol:

[image]

It can be found and changed as usual, for example:

```
app.selection[0].contents = app.selection[0].contents.replace(/\uFEFF/, '#');
```

Result:

[image]

Just in case. The full list (?) of special characters is [here](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#SpecialCharacters.html) and it has no any 'anchor' or 'hyperlink' symbol indeed.

Though I'm not sure that the symbol `\uFEFF` (zero-width no-beak space) has the only purpose in ID.

---

You can add the symbol `\nFEFF` manually at any place of the text any time. So not all `\uFEFF` are real text anchors. To select real text anchors probably it makes sense to loop through hyperlinks. Something like this:

```
app.activeDocument.hyperlinkTextDestinations[0].destinationText.select();
```

It selects the symbol `\uFEFF` if it is a destination of the first hyperlink.